# Upload progress bar with flash

Tags: flash, upload, progress

I am looking for any help, resource, link, step by step tutorial, just everything  on " Flash Upload progress bar".

I would like to make my own upload progress bar with flash which will work with perl, script.

I found a lot of jquery progress bars but it is impossible to edit graphic so it is useless for me since I want my own ;)

any help will be appreciated ;)

Comment: If you don't need to worry about some of the aging browsers, then you can try to use the HTML5 `<progress>` element. You can check out its support at http://caniuse.com/#feat=progressmeter.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same thing.  Check out these two links:

[javascript/flash library for file upload with file size limit and progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856916/javascript-flash-library-for-file-upload-with-file-size-limit-and-progress-bar)

[Flash in Gmail File Upload Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437637/flash-in-gmail-file-upload-progress-bar)